# AnyLogic Stock/Flow ERROR: Couldn't parse expression for (variable name) - Flow

Tags: java, function, parsing, anylogic, runtimeexception

The point of this is to manipulate the birthrates of Mosquitos depending on how hot/cold the temperature is. The temperature is linked to a slider so the user can adjust the temperature during the simulation to observe the changes in Mosquito birthrates. The closer the temperature is to 75, the higher the Mosquito birthrates. But I have this problem:

When I try to run my AnyLogic model, this is the only error I get and it keeps the model from running the simulation window when I try to run it:

```
Couldn't parse expression for Mosquito_Births - Flow: syntax error.
Please check expressions of this variable.
    at group4_assignment2.Main.<init>(Main.java:460)
    at group4_assignment2.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:154)
    at group4_assignment2.Simulation.createRoot(Simulation.java:1)
```

***[here's a picture of the part of the model where the error is found, circled in red]***
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx8hH.png

**Temperature_F** is linked to the function **NEAsia_Temperature_F**. With minimum limit set as 1 and maximum limit set as 120.

The *function* **NEAsia_Temperature_F** is set to return an `int` value, the code is:

```
if(Temperature_F <= 75){
NEAsia_Temperature_F = (Temperature_F / 75);
} else {
NEAsia_Temperature_F = (2 - (Temperature_F / 75));
}
return NEAsia_Temperature_F;
```

**NEAsia_Mosquito_Birthrate** = 0.45

**Mosquito_Births** = (NEAsia_Mosquito_Pop * NEAsia_Mosquito_BirthRate) * (NEAsia_Temperature_F(Temperature_F);)

**NEAsia_Mosquito_Pop** = 100

This is the auto-generated Java code from the model that's associated with the error. The error is on the `if (true) throw new RuntimeException` line on the bottom:

```
  private static String[] _parameterNames_xjal;

  @Override
  public String[] getParameterNames() {
    String[] result = _parameterNames_xjal;
    if (result == null) {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( super.getParameterNames() ) );
      list.add( "NEAsia_Human_FertilityRate" );
      list.add( "NEAsia_Mosquito_BirthRate" );
      list.add( "Mosquito_Mortality_Rate" );
      list.add( "Human_Mortality_Rate" );
      list.add( "Contact_Rate" );
      list.add( "Incubation_Time" );
      list.add( "Infection_Duration" );
      result = list.toArray( new String[ list.size() ] );
      _parameterNames_xjal = result;
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Dynamic (Flow/Auxiliary/Stock) Variables
  {
    if (true) throw new RuntimeException("ERROR during variable generation:\nCouldn't parse expression for Mosquito_Births - Flow: syntax error.\r\nPlease check expressions of this variable.");
  }
```

The issue is apparently stemming from the function call within Mosquito_Births but I'm not getting any other syntax errors anywhere except for that single one when I try to run the model. This took me a long time to get it error-free (except for this last one). Any tips/advice/help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I went over your explanation of the model and it seems there are some things that require clarification/correction:

1. Is the slider not linked to a parameter? Try linking it to a parameter called Temperature_F and change the slider's name to anything else. In such case, the new parameter will have a link connecting it to the flow just like with "NEAsia_Mosquito_Birthrate"
2. I'm assuming your function takes in an argument of type int called "Temperature_F". Is that right? It should.
3. Did you not define the variable "NEAsia_Temperature_F" in your function? Start the function body with

   ```
   int NEAsia_Temperature_F = 0;
   ```
4. Remove the semicolon from the flow equation:

   ```
   Mosquito_Births = (NEAsia_Mosquito_Pop * NEAsia_Mosquito_BirthRate) * (NEAsia_Temperature_F(Temperature_F))
   ```

The above comments are based on the information you provided. With the above steps, I tried to replicate your model, the error was no longer there.

Let me know if this fixes it for you.